# Where is gcc on OSX? I have installed Xcode already

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

I have installed Xcode from the Tool cd, I thought that would let me use gcc from the command line but I can't find it.

What am I missing

**EDIT**

When I wrote *I can't find it*  I meant  "I look for it using `which gcc`"

If `gcc` would have been in the `PATH` in first place, `which` would have find it.

Since `gcc` is not in the `PATH` ( that's what brought me here in first place ) `which` won't find it!

I think that was obvious but I'm making the note here because it wasn't

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too old and out of date. No longer applicable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't check the box that says "UNIX Development Support"[1] (or possibly you unchecked it; I can't remember if it's on by default or not) when you did the install, so it didn't install the necessary symlinks and drivers in `/usr/bin/`.

Reinstall, and make sure to read the descriptions of the configuration options and select the ones that you need.

1: "Optional content to allow command-line development from the boot volume.  Installs a duplicate of the GCC compiler and command line tools blah blah blah..."

Comment: Most likely ... I will reinstall.

Comment: This was it. Now I tried to reinstall but the option is not available :(  I create a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693336/how-to-update-xcode-to-install-unix-development-support

Comment: it was in $home/usr/bin

Answer (score 40):

As of version 4.3.1, XCode is now an application and the command line tools are now available through the Preferences (this is documented in the App Store for XCode under 'What's New in Version 4.3.1' if you click 'More...').  After installing XCode, open it, open the Preferences and click on the Download tab.  Click on 'install' for the 'Command Line Tools' and then sign in with your computer's password.  The code will then be downloaded and installed.

Comment: Can confirm that this is now the way to install gcc.

Answer (score 5):

Something went wrong with your install.

gcc is installed under /usr/bin with a symlink to gcc-4.2:

```
cd diciu$ pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 
volume: /
path: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2

pkgid: com.apple.pkg.gcc4.2Leo
pkg-version: 4.2.0.9000000000.1.1249367152
[..]
pkgid: com.apple.pkg.Xcode3.2.1Update
pkg-version: 1.0.1.1249367152
[..]
pkgid: com.apple.pkg.Xcode3.2.1UpdateUNIXDevSupport
pkg-version: 1.0.1.1249367152
[..]
```

Comment: I didn't know about `pkgutil` - this snippet is definitely a useful one.

Answer (score 4):

On my Mac `$ which gcc` displays `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Comment: Is it possible that `which` returns something if the command doesn't work in first place?

Comment: no, he was just telling you where gcc is SUPPOSED to be. he's saying where gcc is on HIS mac

Comment: @Brian Oh.. then that's a comment, not an answer

Comment: no, it's an answer to your question "Where is gcc on OSX"... the answer is "it should be in /usr/bin"

Comment: @Brian Well, actually the question was "What am I missing" but the obvious answer you've been *"gcc of course!"* so, nevermind. I get your point anyway and it is valid.

Comment: Sorry if I broke protocol, the question title is "Where is gcc on OS X" so I responded; I wasn't trying to offend or make a smart-ass answer.  (FWIW I upvoted an other answer with better info.)  What are the guidelines for providing an answer vs a comment to the question?

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 4.3+ you need to install 'Command Line Tools for Xcode' found here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that rather than not having gcc installed, your $PATH variable is messed up? first check if gcc is in /usr/bin manually. Then echo $PATH...

Comment: That' was what I meant with *I can't find it* :P I've updated my post.

Comment: yes, but my point was that gcc notbeing in your path could be caused by your PATH being wrong, OR by gcc not being present...

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me. It worked for a while and then went away. Reinstall and it will be fixed.

You might want to download Xcode from Apple while you are at it. Almost guaranteed to be fresher / more up-to-date since Xcode is rapidly updated. Current Xcode is 3.2.1.10. You need an Apple ID to download, but that also gives you access to the development site. All free... .

---

It is 1/6/2014. Current Xcode is 5.0.1

---

It is 2016 -- Current Xcode is 8.0. I think this question should be closed now.

Comment: +1 @drewk Thanks, I tried do downloaded it from I couldn't pass the firewall ( or the antivirus I don't know ) so today I brought my install CD and this is what happened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693336/how-to-update-xcode-to-install-unix-development-support :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to install 'command line tools' by clicking Preferences-Downloads-command line tools.