# Unable to build mercurial on OSX - Python.h not found

Tags: xcode, macos, mercurial, build

For what I've read I need Python-Dev, how do I install it on OSX?

I think the problem I have, is, my Xcode was not properly installed, and I don't have the paths where I should.

This previous question:

[Where is gcc on OSX? I have installed Xcode already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685887/where-is-gcc-on-osx-i-have-installed-xcode-already)

Was about I couldn't find gcc, now I can't find Python.h

Should I just link my /Developer directory to somewhere else in /usr/ ???

This is my output:

```
$ sudo easy_install mercurial
Password:
Searching for mercurial
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/mercurial/
Reading http://www.selenic.com/mercurial
Best match: mercurial 1.5.1
Downloading http://mercurial.selenic.com/release/mercurial-1.5.1.tar.gz
Processing mercurial-1.5.1.tar.gz
Running mercurial-1.5.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-_7RaTq/mercurial-1.5.1/egg-dist-tmp-l7JP3u
mercurial/base85.c:12:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might depend on what version of Mac OSX you have, I have it in these spots:

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5/Python.h
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5/Python.h
```

Also I believe the version of python that comes with Xcode is a custom build that plays well with xcode but you have to jump through some hoops if you use another dev environment.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked and yes, is there also. Now the question would be, how to make gcc find it. Is there a way to globally modify the *include path* ?

Comment: @OscarRyz: Pass the `-I` flag to gcc: `gcc -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5`

Answer (score 6):

I was struggling with this problem all day today.

I eventually discovered a [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20141221052542/http://www.jaharmi.com/2011/11/12/reinstall_xcode_if_easy_install_fails_with_missing_files_like_python_h) that claimed that all one needed to do was to reinstall Xcode, or install the latest version (4.3.2, as of this writing).

So I tried that.  It did not help; not on its own.  But then I went a step further: I fired up Xcode.app, and once I had done that, I opened the Xcode..Preferences menu item, and then go to the Downloads tab, and say that you want to install the "Command Line Tools"

Once I did that, and then re-ran easy_install (in my case I was trying to "easy_install dulwich" to satisfy a hg-git dependency), it was able to properly find Python.h for me.

Comment: IIRC my problem was I didn't installed command line tools back then.

Comment: Indeed, looking over your other questions, I see now that this same answer is provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9464735/36585

Comment: Link is broken now

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to build Mercurial from source? There are [binary packages available](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads), including the nice [MacHg](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/) which comes with a bundled Mercurial.