# Can't install psycopg2 with pip in virtualenv on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip, psycopg2

I am following Heroku's tutorial to deploy a Django app: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#prerequisites.

Everything is working fine until I get to this part:

```
$ pip install Django psycopg2
```

I can install Django by itself, but the probelm is with psycopg2.

I keep getting this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lpq

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

ld: library not found for -lpq

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/_4/p6l0y0t51hd4xbq7llbyshmw0000gn/T//cc0L10mI.out (No such file or directory)

error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

I've installed PostgreSQL 9.1 on my machine.

Also, in the output, there are bunch of lines like this:

```
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.4 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090004 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o
```

I'm not really sure what it means, but I do notice that it has "macosx-10.6" in it so I'm wondering if that could be the issue? I'm on 10.7.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025594/osx-ld-library-not-found-for-lssl

Comment: After running `brew install postgres`, I was able to run `pip install psycopg2` without any issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer to [official installation guide](http://initd.org/psycopg/install) of psycopg:

> Installing on Mac OS X As a first option, please consider using a
>   **packaged version** of Psycopg from Fink or MacPorts.
>
> If you still want to build Psycopg from source, take a look at [these](http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2010/11/11/links-about-building-psycopg-mac-os-x/)
>   articles.

Comment: Ok, I just installed psycopg2 using macports in the virtualenv. I'm guessing this does the same thing that pip install does in the tutorial? As in, I would just replace this step? Reason I'm asking is because the app is still failing when I launch it. When I type Heroku Logs, this is one of the lines I get: `raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)`

Comment: Using MacPorts to install won't work inside a virtualenv environment. To get your app working, you should check out those articles about building from source :)

Comment: Ok, I followed the instructions in one of those articles: http://blog.timc3.com/2010/08/20/psycopg2-os-x-_pqbackendpid/, and I got psycopg2 to install on my machine. However, i'm still getting the same error within the virtualenv environment. I'm not too sure how I would build from source within a virtualenv.

Comment: Did you activated your virtualenv before running the last command `python setup.py install` ?

Comment: That worked! Thank you! A more explicit version for those wondering: I recreated the hellodjango directory and went through the steps, and instead of doing 'pip install psycopg2', I just downloaded psycopg2-2.4.4.tar.gz and installed it using "python setup.py install".

Comment: Fink! MacPorts! Retro! :)

Answer (score 183):

Just would like to share. The following code worked for me:

```
env LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib' pip install psycopg2==2.5.2
```

I am using macOS Sierra and psql 9.6.1.

I got the lib path from the `pg_config` command.

Comment: this was your first answer to SO, and it works great. Thank you for taking the time to put it here. This solution works to install psycopg2 within a `virtualenv` with postgres and dependencies installed with `brew`.

Comment: `pg_config --ldflags` will give you the specific path for your setup.

Comment: Works for me on macos 10.14.4 with python 3.7.2 and postgres 11.2. Thanks!

Comment: @Chuan's answer working on for me on OS Mojave in Virtualbox. Was running into a very nasty psycopg2 wheel build error. exporting `LDFLAGS` via `pg_config --ldflags` worked

Comment: This solution works for me in Mojave 10.14.3. Thanks!

Comment: Works in Mojave 10.14.4 as well with Python 3.7 in virtualenv. Thank you

Comment: This worked for me on OS X Catalina with postgresql installed via Brew and pip-installing pyscopg2 in a virtualenv.

`LDFLAGS=$(pg_config --ldflags)  pip install psycopg2`

Comment: Works in Catalina with psql from brew, also I have used `pipenv` and not `pip` and worked too

Comment: With last version of psycopg2 (2.8.4) on last version of MAC OS X (v10.15.4)


   `env LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib' pip install psycopg2==2.8.4`

Comment: Works on Catalina (10.15.7) with python 3.7.8 on virtualenv

Answer (score 58):

I am using **MAC OS CATALINA** verison **10.15.5** with **python3** and **psql (PostgreSQL) 12.3**. Here is what worked for me:

Try installing openssl using brew

```
brew install openssl
```

after that export these variables in the terminal.

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

verify these variables have been exported by `echo $LDFLAGS` and after that you are good to go with installation of psycopg2 by typing

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

Comment: The LDFLAGS environment variable was enough for me - I didn't need the CPPFLAGS one too.

Answer (score 35):

First, download [`Postgres.app`](http://postgresapp.com/).

Then, before running `pip install psycopg2`, put the binary in your path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin
```

**NOTICE**:

`9.3` stands for version and will differ over time.

Comment: Thanks, I found this reply most useful, as it does not require MacPorts or any other tools.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. For the future reference for those who might need it: macOS 10.15, 2020 Intel macbook pro. Postgres 14.

Answer (score 17):

### Generic LDFLAGS variable set

Just export LDFLAGS before installing it, here is generic command which shall work for OS X (and I believe any LINUX system which has same error):

```
 LDFLAGS="$(pg_config --ldflags)" pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: this is better as it works for openssl installed in different paths

Answer (score 9):

The workaround is to intsall 'psycopg2-binary' package

Answer (score 7):

Install `postgres` with `brew`:

```
brew install postgres
```

Then, in your virtualenv install `psycopg2` with this command:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: These commands ran beautifully, but python still could not find `psycopg2`. I had to then run `pip install psycopg2-binary` which finally worked. There's probably some redundant operations here. I don't care. It finally works.

Answer (score 2):

Focusing on this line: ld: library not found for -lpq

psycopg2, like most 3rd-party postgres libraries, wants 'pg_config' available in your path. I'm *guessing* that's your problem.

Type 'pg_config' at the command prompt. I hope you see that it's not found.  If not, do a:

sudo find / -name pg_config

to find where it's at, and then add that location to your path, run 'pg_config' and see it succeed, and then finally, re-run pip.

*the find command is searching starting at your root dir; it will take a few minutes*.

Comment: hey, thanks for the response. however, when I type 'pg_config', it is found and there isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying so many things and nothing worked. However, if you use Xcode CLI Tools on Mojave and have a problem installing psycopg2, try the following command and try to install psycopg2 again.

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

This was described as a Mojave Issue: [Pillowissue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3438#issuecomment-435169249)

In my case, this solved the issue.

Comment: Worked for me, ran that command outside the virtualenv, activated the env again, and installed with no issues

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 1):

First this:
`pip install psycopg2-binary`
and then:
`pip install psycopg2` worked.

Answer (score 0):

The following post helped me get it working:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10326004/1361851

Had to install "command line tools" for Xcode and then I was able to pip install with the virtualenv just the same as the heroku tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above solutions but the only thing that resolved the issue for me is simply updating Xcode CLI utilities through the official App Store.

Answer (score -1):

Once I was also facing the same problem on Mac then I figured out that psycopg2 has a dependency on GCC library.

> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
>
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"

Just run this command and then try to run

> pip install psycopg2

Hope this will work.

Comment: Hi Harsh, would you mind explaining a bit more how this solves the problem?

Comment: @AnnaIraHurnaus Using the **export** command, the PATH variable is going to hold the newly added directory.
This sets the path of the GCC which is required in installing psycopg2 .
Hope you got it.