# OSX ld: library not found for -lssl

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, macos, virtualenv

I am trying to install mysqlclient in virtrualenv on OSX high sierra, with python 3. And got the following error:

```
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient, coverage, django-coverage-plugin, Pygments, babel, alabaster, sphinxcontrib-websupport, imagesize, pyparsing, packaging, snowballstemmer, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, docutils, Sphinx, typing, django-extensions, Werkzeug, django-test-plus, text-unidecode, python-dateutil, Faker, factory-boy, sqlparse, django-debug-toolbar, decorator, simplegeneric, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, appnope, pickleshare, ptyprocess, pexpect, ipython-genutils, traitlets, parso, jedi, ipython, ipdb, py, pluggy, attrs, pytest, pytest-django, termcolor, pytest-sugar
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /private/var/virtualenvs/todobackend/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/80/lb0c7r0s5bj3rfrvv1pp85g80000gn/T/pip-build-sqswyq3d/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/80/lb0c7r0s5bj3rfrvv1pp85g80000gn/T/pip-g8z3z8q5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /private/var/virtualenvs/todobackend/bin/../include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
    clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -Dversion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.10/include/mysql -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.o -fno-omit-frame-pointer
    In file included from _mysql.c:29:
    In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.10/include/mysql/mysql.h:64:
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.10/include/mysql/mysql/client_plugin.h:97:3: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
      MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
      ^
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.10/include/mysql/mysql/client_plugin.h:92:16: note: expanded from macro 'MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER'
      int (*deinit)();                                      \
                   ^
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.10/include/mysql/mysql/client_plugin.h:107:3: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
      MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
      ^
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.10/include/mysql/mysql/client_plugin.h:92:16: note: expanded from macro 'MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER'
      int (*deinit)();                                      \
                   ^
    2 warnings generated.
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.10/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/private/var/virtualenvs/todobackend/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/80/lb0c7r0s5bj3rfrvv1pp85g80000gn/T/pip-build-sqswyq3d/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/80/lb0c7r0s5bj3rfrvv1pp85g80000gn/T/pip-g8z3z8q5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /private/var/virtualenvs/todobackend/bin/../include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/80/lb0c7r0s5bj3rfrvv1pp85g80000gn/T/pip-build-sqswyq3d/mysqlclient/
```

Tried `xcode-select --install` but didn't work. And I already have mysql server installed on the same computer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same issue after upgrading to osx Mojave, and on python 3.7.2. This is what worked for me:

```
# Required for mysqlclient, see brew info openssl
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"

pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Hope it helps. For more see [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/169).

Comment: I was getting this same error and these commands fixed it on my local, but when I try to deploy to heroku I get the same error, any idea how I might fix that?

Comment: You probably need to install openssl on your instance. I'm actually not familiar with heroku. I realize you have less control over the server vs for example a AWS ec2 instance, which is what I use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have openssl@1.1, you'll run into errors because `mysqlclient` uses `/usr/local/opt/openssl` and that's not present in your directory. So, create a symbolic link with the name `openssl` pointing to `openssl@1.1`.

This shell command worked for me -

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 /usr/local/opt/openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [radtek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53962090/4960855), I resolved it with this command alone:

```sh
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
```

To make it work for future terminal sessions too:

```sh
echo 'export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"' >> ~/.zshrc
```