# pip install error for mysqlclient command -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize failed with error code 1

Tags: python, mysql, pip, mysql-python

I am trying to install `mysqlclient` for a Django app but I am getting the following error when running `sudo pip install mysqlclient`

```
Command "/Users/jimmymona/Development/onBeat/TFS/USDSA/udsa_content_repository/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-6mmeJ5/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-wmyB7z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/jimmymona/Development/onBeat/TFS/USDSA/udsa_content_repository/venv/include/site/python2.7/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-6mmeJ5/mysqlclient/
```

Full terminal output:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz (85kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 987kB/s 
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/jimmymona/Development/onBeat/TFS/USDSA/udsa_content_repository/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-6mmeJ5/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-wmyB7z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/jimmymona/Development/onBeat/TFS/USDSA/udsa_content_repository/venv/include/site/python2.7/mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1126:33: warning: passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
            return PyInt_FromString(rowitem, NULL, 10);
                                    ^~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/intobject.h:34:46: note: passing argument to parameter here
    PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyInt_FromString(char*, char**, int);
                                                 ^
    1 warning generated.
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:304:23: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                int j, n2=PySequence_Size(fun);
                       ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:892:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            len = mysql_real_escape_string_quote(&(self->connection), out, in, size, '\'');
                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:897:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            len = mysql_escape_string(out, in, size);
                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1126:33: warning: passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
            return PyInt_FromString(rowitem, NULL, 10);
                                    ^~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/intobject.h:34:46: note: passing argument to parameter here
    PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyInt_FromString(char*, char**, int);
                                                 ^
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1215:19: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = strlen(buf);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1217:19: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = strlen(buf);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1253:23: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = strlen(buf);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1255:23: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = strlen(buf);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    8 warnings generated.
    cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/jimmymona/Development/onBeat/TFS/USDSA/udsa_content_repository/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-6mmeJ5/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-wmyB7z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/jimmymona/Development/onBeat/TFS/USDSA/udsa_content_repository/venv/include/site/python2.7/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-6mmeJ5/mysqlclient/
```

I also tried using `MySQL-python` but that gave the same error.

Anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: `ld: library not found for -lssl`

Comment: Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: As I found this for MacOS, `brew install openssl`

Comment: I"m getting `Warning: openssl 1.0.2r is already installed and up-to-date`

Comment: See here: https://superuser.com/questions/1089390/how-to-install-libssl-dev-libffi-dev-on-mac-os

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSX ld: library not found for -lssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025594/osx-ld-library-not-found-for-lssl)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ld%3A+library+not+found+for+-lssl