# Cant install mysqlclient on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run my windows created python script on MacOS.

I have managed to install all of the needed modules apart from MySQLdb.

I am trying to install from pip3 using this command:

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

But get a massive error:

```
    Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/38/c5f8bac9c50f3042c8f05615f84206f77f03db79781db841898fde1bb284/mysqlclient-1.4.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/11/bj20_z594y1562dx9p3bc4km0000gn/T/pip-install-cbceeulv/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/11/bj20_z594y1562dx9p3bc4km0000gn/T/pip-install-cbceeulv/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/11/bj20_z594y1562dx9p3bc4km0000gn/T/pip-wheel-md6mses2 --python-tag cp37
       cwd: /private/var/folders/11/bj20_z594y1562dx9p3bc4km0000gn/T/pip-install-cbceeulv/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (30 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  xcrun -sdk macosx clang -arch x86_64 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Headers -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.4 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  xcrun -sdk macosx clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  ld: library not found for -lssl
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/11/bj20_z594y1562dx9p3bc4km0000gn/T/pip-install-cbceeulv/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/11/bj20_z594y1562dx9p3bc4km0000gn/T/pip-install-cbceeulv/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/11/bj20_z594y1562dx9p3bc4km0000gn/T/pip-record-zi37f1af/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/11/bj20_z594y1562dx9p3bc4km0000gn/T/pip-install-cbceeulv/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    xcrun -sdk macosx clang -arch x86_64 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Headers -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.4 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    xcrun -sdk macosx clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/11/bj20_z594y1562dx9p3bc4km0000gn/T/pip-install-cbceeulv/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/11/bj20_z594y1562dx9p3bc4km0000gn/T/pip-install-cbceeulv/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/11/bj20_z594y1562dx9p3bc4km0000gn/T/pip-record-zi37f1af/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried multiple forum posts that I have found and nothing is working. I have also tried to build from Source but I get an error about ConfigParser not being installed - which it has been via pip.

Please could someone help?!

P.S Pip has been updated to the latest version.

Comment: Did you follow the MacOS instructions on the package's page https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSX ld: library not found for -lssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025594/osx-ld-library-not-found-for-lssl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
brew install mysql
```

or

https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/169