# I can't install psycopg2

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2

I have been trying to use python for a while now and have been having trouble with pip and installing modules. I installed pycharm to see if it would take care of any wrong installations of python. Then I tried running the command: pip install psycopg2 and got the following error (Thank you in advance!):

```
    Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for psycopg2, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jk/5fnymm0d13g2v3tcrsys66dm0000gn/T/pip-install-2wfw70_y/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jk/5fnymm0d13g2v3tcrsys66dm0000gn/T/pip-install-2wfw70_y/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jk/5fnymm0d13g2v3tcrsys66dm0000gn/T/pip-record-4ffvjwp_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/jk/5fnymm0d13g2v3tcrsys66dm0000gn/T/pip-install-2wfw70_y/psycopg2/
    Complete output (151 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/green.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/pqpath.o
    psycopg/pqpath.c:138:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1717:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        ret = 1;
              ^
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1822:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/utils.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/bytes_format.o
    In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:82:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/libpq_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/libpq_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/libpq_support.c:30:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/win32_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/win32_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/win32_support.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/solaris_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/solaris_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/solaris_support.c:29:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/aix_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/aix_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/aix_support.c:29:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/column_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/column_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/column_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/replication_connection_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_message_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_message_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/replication_message_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/diagnostics_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/error_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/error_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/conninfo_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/conninfo_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/conninfo_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/notify_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/xid_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_binary.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_list.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
    In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/typecast.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/aix_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jk/5fnymm0d13g2v3tcrsys66dm0000gn/T/pip-install-2wfw70_y/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jk/5fnymm0d13g2v3tcrsys66dm0000gn/T/pip-install-2wfw70_y/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jk/5fnymm0d13g2v3tcrsys66dm0000gn/T/pip-record-4ffvjwp_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/davidkim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: install `psycopg2-binary` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install psycopg2 with pip in virtualenv on Mac OS X 10.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678408/cant-install-psycopg2-with-pip-in-virtualenv-on-mac-os-x-10-7)

Comment: Does the binary version work the same though?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can install a pre-build binary directly, so you don't need to gather dependencies and compile it locally:

```
$ pip install psycopg2-binary
```

You can find more information on this topic here:

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#psycopg-vs-psycopg-binary