# pip install django_heroku ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python, django

I tried to run the command pip install django_heroku in my terminal but it gave me this error. Ive tried to run it in the virtual environment but it still doesn't work. Ive removed some of the code since it has exceeded the 30,000 character limit. I'm pretty new to Django and to programming in general so this is quite complicated for me. Please help me. Thank you very much.

```
    Last login: Fri Oct 30 11:02:23 on ttys000
    john@MacBook-Pro-john ~ % pip install django_heroku 
    Collecting django_heroku
      Using cached django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
    Collecting psycopg2
      Using cached psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
    Requirement already satisfied: django in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django_heroku) (3.1.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: dj-database-url>=0.5.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django_heroku) (0.5.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: whitenoise in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django_heroku) (5.2.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django->django_heroku) (2020.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: asgiref~=3.2.10 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django->django_heroku) (3.2.10)
    Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django->django_heroku) (0.4.1)
    Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
      Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/lf/xxr916px64v56ysf7mzg19dh0000gn/T/pip-install-j_vf2_qy/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/lf/xxr916px64v56ysf7mzg19dh0000gn/T/pip-install-j_vf2_qy/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/lf/xxr916px64v56ysf7mzg19dh0000gn/T/pip-wheel-ubkf3qey
           cwd: /private/var/folders/lf/xxr916px64v56ysf7mzg19dh0000gn/T/pip-install-j_vf2_qy/psycopg2/
      Complete output (151 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      
      copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      running build_ext
      building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
     
      psycopg/pqpath.c:138:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                      PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      psycopg/pqpath.c:1717:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          ret = 1;
                ^
      psycopg/pqpath.c:1822:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                      PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      3 warnings generated.
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/utils.o
     
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
      ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/libpq_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/libpq_support.o
      In file included from psycopg/libpq_support.c:30:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
      ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/aix_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/aix_support.o
      In file included from psycopg/aix_support.c:29:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
      ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o
      In file included from psycopg/replication_connection_type.c:28:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
      ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_message_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_message_type.o
      In file included from psycopg/replication_message_type.c:28:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
      ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o
      In file included from psycopg/diagnostics_type.c:28:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
      ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/error_type.o
      In file included from psycopg/error_type.c:28:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
      ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}

                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_int.o
      
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/notify_type.o
      In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:28:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
      ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/xid_type.o
      

      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
      
      In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:28:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
      ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/typecast.o
      gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/aix_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
      ld: library not found for -lssl
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
      Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
    Failed to build psycopg2
    Installing collected packages: psycopg2, django-heroku
        Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/lf/xxr916px64v56ysf7mzg19dh0000gn/T/pip-install-j_vf2_qy/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/lf/xxr916px64v56ysf7mzg19dh0000gn/T/pip-install-j_vf2_qy/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/lf/xxr916px64v56ysf7mzg19dh0000gn/T/pip-record-otiv1qyj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/psycopg2
             cwd: /private/var/folders/lf/xxr916px64v56ysf7mzg19dh0000gn/T/pip-install-j_vf2_qy/psycopg2/
        Complete output (151 lines):
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
        creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
     copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
        running build_ext
        building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
        creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
        creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/pqpath.o
        psycopg/pqpath.c:138:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                        PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        psycopg/pqpath.c:1717:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            ret = 1;
                  ^
        psycopg/pqpath.c:1822:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                        PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        3 warnings generated.
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/bytes_format.o
        In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:82:
        In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
        ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
        static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                    ^
        1 warning generated.
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/libpq_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/libpq_support.o
        In file included from psycopg/libpq_support.c:30:
        In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
        ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
        static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}      
                    ^
        1 warning generated.
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_int.o
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_type.o
       
        In file included from psycopg/column_type.c:28:
        In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
        ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
        static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                    ^
        1 warning generated.
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o
        In file included from psycopg/replication_connection_type.c:28:
        In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
        ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
        static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                    ^
        1 warning generated.
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_message_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_message_type.o
        In file included from psycopg/replication_message_type.c:28:
        In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
        ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
        static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                    ^
        1 warning generated.
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o
        In file included from psycopg/diagnostics_type.c:28:
        In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
        ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
        static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                    ^
        1 warning generated.
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/error_type.o
        In file included from psycopg/error_type.c:28:
        In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
        ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
        static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                    ^
        1 warning generated.
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/conninfo_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/conninfo_type.o
        In file included from psycopg/conninfo_type.c:28:
        In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
        ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
        static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                    ^
       
        In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:28:
        In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
        ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
        static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                    ^
        1 warning generated.
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/xid_type.o

      

        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
        In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:28:
        In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
        ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
        static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                    ^
        1 warning generated.
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/typecast.o
      
        ld: library not found for -lssl
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
        error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/lf/xxr916px64v56ysf7mzg19dh0000gn/T/pip-install-j_vf2_qy/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/lf/xxr916px64v56ysf7mzg19dh0000gn/T/pip-install-j_vf2_qy/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/lf/xxr916px64v56ysf7mzg19dh0000gn/T/pip-record-otiv1qyj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
    john@MacBook-Pro-john ~ %
```

Comment: Your issue here is installed psycopg2 rather than django_heroku, try installing the binary first:`pip install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: The following should help explain my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678408/cant-install-psycopg2-with-pip-in-virtualenv-on-mac-os-x-10-7

Comment: hi I've tried to pip install psycopg2-binary but it still gave me the same error

Comment: its still gave me the error error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1