# How do I build PIL on OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, osx-mountain-lion

When I try to build PIL on Mac OS X 10.8.1 Mountain Lion, I get the following result:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
Password:
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
building '_imaging' extension
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -IlibImaging -I/opt/local/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/usr/local/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/_imaging.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
_imaging.c:75:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include "Python.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Is this an upgrade or a clean install? I can't reproduce on a clean install.

Comment: This was an upgrade from Lion (10.7.4 I think), which also had Python manually upgraded to 2.7. Since Pillow works on a clean install, I think that's an acceptable enough answer for me. Thanks for checking on this, and for your work on Pillow :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIL does not keep up with support for new operating systems (by making changes to setup.py for new lib dirs, etc). But intstead of PIL, you can use the "friendly PIL fork" **Pillow**:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow

And if you get the same error, please report the issue:

- https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/new

Comment: I should have mentioned that I got the same error when I tried to install Pillow. I then went back to the manual install method I describe in my answer.

Comment: You should also report an issue so we can fix it :-) https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/new

Comment: FYI: On a fresh install of Mountain Lion, Pillow installed okay as of Jan 2012

Answer (score 0):

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686520/unable-to-build-mercurial-on-osx-python-h-not-found), I was able to find Python.h in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7. (note that i have Xcode installed)

I then ran `sudo python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7:/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include`

(note: `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include` added because stdio.h was missing once the Python.h was resolved)

Finally, I ran `sudo python setup.py install`