# Error installing PIL on Mac OS 10.8.4

Tags: python, macos, web, python-imaging-library

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: You might want to switch to Pillow: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.4.0 -- PIL doesn't seem to be well-maintained on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, assuming you are using Homebrew, type:

```
brew install Homebrew/python/pillow
```

Pillow is basically the same as PIL.

Try following 2 commands if python has trouble locating the package.

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages

echo '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' > ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

Answer (score 1):

xcode-select --install

may be can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat remember this exact problem. Have you installed the Xcode command line tools? That cured my headaches.

You can find it here.. https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

From Xcode's Preferences menu, install the Command Line Tools (Downloads/Components tab).

supporting references:
[gcc-4.2 failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473066/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-status-1)
[I can't install 'pip install pil' in Osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484876/i-cant-install-pip-install-pil-in-osx)

Comment: I DO have the Xcode command line tools installed. That's why it's bugging me. My colleagues are using osx 10.7 and there not having any issues. It might be something to do with this version