# How to update Xcode to install "UNIX Development Support"?

Tags: xcode, macos, unix, xcode3.2

I installed Xcode a long time ago.

Apparently I didn't check back then the "UNIX Development Support" checkbox.

Now I want to have them but when I click on the installation this is what appears:

[image: disabled]

The *UNIX Development Support* check box is disabled

**Q:** How can I install the UNIX Development Support?  Is there a way to run some script that creates all the needed links from `/Developer/` to `/usr/bin` ?

**EDIT:**
Note: This is for old Xcode 3. Screens and tool names differ for Xcode 4 ("Unix Command Line Tools")

Comment: You can also download it here:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally.

I had to download from [Apple's website](http://developer.apple.com) the latest version of Xcode 3 (3.2) along with the iPhone SDK that I won't use in the near feature.

This time the "UNIX Development Support" was enabled:

[image: Xcode 3.2 Installation]

So now I can compile from the command line!

Comment: 3.2 is the old version. The answer by @eigschpee is more relevant.

Answer (score 37):

With Xcode 4.3 (from Apple App Store) you can enable Unix Command Line Tools via the Xcode Menu: Preferences ->  Download -> Components

Answer (score 5):

In xcode > 4.5 select Preferences -> Download -> Components -> Command Line Tools

Answer (score 0):

In the Xcode `.dmg` file, there is a `Packages` folder. You can manually install `DeveloperToolsCLI.pkg` which creates the link in `/usr/bin`.

*At least, it worked for me.*

Answer (score 0):

You can also right click the "Install Xcode X.X" icon and Show Package Contents then in `Contents > Resources > Packages`, you will find many packages from among which resides DeveloperToolsCLI.pkg. This package installs the files you want in /usr/bin.

Answer (score -1):

You should uninstall and then re-install the developer tools.

To uninstall the tools, run the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Comment: That's what I tried and had the same results :( I'm downloading the 2gb of the latest Xcode version too see if that works :(