# Booting xv6 on macbook OSX High Sierra (10.13.3)

Tags: gcc, macos-high-sierra, i386, xv6

I am following the instructions in the most popular answer to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685887/where-is-gcc-on-osx-i-have-installed-xcode-already) and when I attempt to run

```
make TOOLCHAIN=i386-elf- qemu
```

it refuses to run giving me the following error...

```
***
*** Error: Couldn't find an i386-*-elf version of GCC/binutils.
*** Is the directory with i386-jos-elf-gcc in your PATH?
*** If your i386-*-elf toolchain is installed with a command
*** prefix other than 'i386-jos-elf-', set your TOOLPREFIX
*** environment variable to that prefix and run 'make' again.
*** To turn off this error, run 'gmake TOOLPREFIX= ...'.
***
gcc -m32 -gdwarf-2 -Wa,-divide   -c -o usys.o usys.S
clang: error: unsupported argument '-divide' to option 'Wa,'
make: *** [usys.o] Error 1
```

I am unsure how to resolve this and unsure where to find the texinfo that the person was refering to in their answer to the linked post. I am also unsure where i386 installed itself. I am aware that I am omitting the -nox command from the command line instruction, but I tried that as well. We have setup a window manager for xv6 that works properly and I was wanting to be able to run it on my machine but cannot get it to work.

Thanks for any help!